# Game design equation (Two variables(multiple two variables) and one Result (for every case)) how to make the Equation?

Tags: analysis, regression

I tried to solve this using multiple methods but i couldn't figure it out.
i don't know what to use in order to solve this 
basically i have an input x and x2

### Heading

### when x = 1 and x2 = 1   Y = 45

### when x = 1 and x2 = -1  Y = 315

### when x = -1 and x2 = 1  Y = 135

### when x = -1 and x2 = -1  Y = 225

### when x =  0 and x2 =  1  Y = 90

### when x =  0 and x2 = -1  Y = 270

### when x =  1 and x2 =  0  Y = 360

### when x =  -1 and x2 =  0  Y = 180

To explain it more i want an equation that when ever i input x ,x2 values in it i get the same y value.
Ii don't know if its feasible or if math can deal with that type of situation but i believe that somehow there should be a way to make that equation
I tried to use Excel to solve this as a regression but it didn't work

Comment: If this is for game design, maybe just manually code a function with an if statement to find these values for you? If there is an element of continuity, then can you graph what that would look like?

Comment: Thanks but i don't want to code it i coded it all ready i want to know if our knowledge in math can be powerful enough to create something in one line rather than coding it in 20 or so, plus i want to know because i face problems like these a lot of times and i end up coding a solution for a problem that could have been solved mathematically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you are asking how to find an angle given 2 coordinates, in vast majority of languages, there is a function `atan2(y,x)` (or with similar name) that allows you to pass coordinates and get the value of the angle:
$$
Y=\frac{180}{\pi}\mathop{\mathrm{atan2}}(x_2,x_1).
$$ 
If we insist we want integer number from $1$ to $360$, we can add modulus shift:
$$
Y = \mathrm{rem}\left(\left[\frac{180}{\pi}\mathop{\mathrm{atan2}}(x_2,x_1)-1\right], 360\right)+1.
$$
In C it would be translated as `((int)round(180/PI*atan2(x2,x1)-1) % 360)+1`

If we do not want trigonometric function for suchsimple problem and also do not want to use precalculated array, we can go like this.
You can represent your data in a table $A_{ij}$, where $i,j=-1,0,1$:
$$
A=45 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 5 & 4 & 3 \\
 6 & \cdot & 2 \\
 7 & 8 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

All numbers except 8 can be represented as a [bilinear interpolation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bilinear_interpolation) of the corners:
$$
Y'=4-2x_2-x_1x_2,\qquad A'=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 5 & 4 & 3 \\
 6 & \cdot & 2 \\
 7 & 4 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Now we need to add 4 to the bottom 4 to get 8. We can do it with the trick $2 (x_1+1) \left(1-x_2^2\right)$. Finally:
$$
Y=45\left(4-2x_2-x_1x_2+2 (x_1+1) \left(1-x_2^2\right)\right)
$$

Comment: Sir i want first to thank you very much, then to ask you what should i learn in order to know the information that you used, you made something seemed impossible possible i never though that math can do something like that. can you please lead me to a book or topic or anything that i can start with.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *easy* formula that gets all results in one equation, but the code can be made significantly easier than 8 cases as presented in the question. Pseudocode:

```
if (x==0) 
  {m=8, d=2}
else
  {m=6+2*x, d=x}
Y=45*((m+d*x2) % 8)
```

The $\%$-operator is the calculating the remainder of the term $m+d*x2$ modulo 8.

This will give $0$ instead if $360$ for $x=1, x2=0$, but I assume that this is OK as the design seems to be based on angles (I assume for movement).