# How to make an equation out of variables in this example

Tags: calculus

A week ago I have asked a question in Mathematics about a Game design issue where i wanted to make an equation out of two variables.
The answer was astonishing to me but i didn't know how to solve the question the way it was solved.
I ended up drowning in research trying to find out how to do something similar.
In game design, i face a lot of issues where i know that if i was good at math i could solve it easily but i end up going the long way and code every possible output out of every possible input which takes a long time and makes the game run slower
this is the question

[Game design equation (Two variables(multiple two variables) and one Result (for every case)) how to make the Equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080322/game-design-equation-two-variablesmultiple-two-variables-and-one-result-for)

i need to at least have an idea to what subject or skill to learn so that i can have that kind of skill
Thank you.

Comment: What is your question? What parts of mathematics you need to understand the previous answer?

Comment: @lightxbulb Roughly speaking I think the OP is asking for guide concerning "How to learn mathematical-modeling in Game Design related issues". In my opinion this counts as off-topic hence it can be seen as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Seriously... i just want to know how to make an equation when you have two variables and one result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other posters have mentioned, this is a somewhat abstract question, but given the question you linked to, I'd suggest the following:

- If you haven't done so, a basic course in algebra / pre-calculus, which should cover topics such as functions, equations, geometry, etc.
- An introductory calculus course
- An introductory linear algebra course
- Perhaps also a basic course in statistics

Best,
avi

Comment: Thank you, i am doing exactly this right now.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reasonable way to do that without knowing what type of equation you are seeking. There is an infinite amount of equations that will satisfy the conditions of two variables and one result.